# Parsing XML attributes with minidom

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, dom, xml-parsing

I want to parse the contents of an XML file with Python minidom.
Say I have an xml doc like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<library>
 <book>
  <title>Sandman Volume 1: Preludes and Nocturnes</title>
  <author>Neil Gaiman</author>
 </book>
 <book owner="jim" type="fiction">
  <title>Good Omens</title>
  <author>Neil Gamain</author>
  <author>Terry Pratchett</author>
  </book>
 <book owner = "john" type="fiction">
  <title>All the Lovely Things</title>
  <author>John Wize</author>
 </book>
 <book owner="john" type="non-fiction">
  <title>Beginning Python</title>
  <author>Peter Norton, et al</author>
 </book>
<book owner="john" type="fiction">
  <title>Beginning Python</title>
  <author>Peter Norton, et al</author>
 </book>
</library>
```

I want to parse the document and output all the book titles from owner "john" to the file, but not the ones with owner = "john".

my script so far:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
import csv
from itertools import count

# Declare Counter
c = count(1)

def writeToCSV(myLibrary):
    with open('csvout.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        writer.writerow(['key', 'title', 'author', 'author']) #added key
        books = myLibrary.getElementsByTagName("book")
        for book in books:
            titleValue = book.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].data
            authors =[]
            for author in book.getElementsByTagName("author"):
                authors.append(author.childNodes[0].data)
            writer.writerow([c.next()] + [titleValue] + authors)

# Create XML objects            
doc = parse('library.xml')
myLibrary = doc.getElementsByTagName("library")[0]

# Call function
writeToCSV(myLibrary)
```

my script was written before I added the book attributes in. My output was:

```
key,title,author,author
1,Sandman Volume 1: Preludes and Nocturnes,Neil Gaiman
2,Good Omens,Neil Gamain,Terry Pratchett
3,All the Lovely Things,John Wize
4,Beginning Python,"Peter Norton, et al"
```

If I wanted to only display the books that have the attribute "john" and "fiction", how do I do it?

Comment: Any specific reason you are using the minidom library over ElementTree here? The DOM is *very* verbose and cumbersome to work with.

Comment: Mainly because it's my first venture into the world of Python XML parsing. I've spent a few weeks learning bits of minidom.
Do you think I would be better off starting again and learning ElementTree then?

Comment: yes, that API is simpler and you can upgrade to lxml for powerful XPath queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to check the attribute `owner` like here: `if book.getAttribute('owner') == 'james':`.

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
import csv
from itertools import count

# Declare Counter
c = count(1)

def writeToCSV(myLibrary):
    with open('csvout.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerow(['key', 'title', 'author', 'author']) #added key
    books = myLibrary.getElementsByTagName("book")
    for book in books:
        if book.getAttribute('owner') == 'james':
            titleValue = book.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].data
            authors =[]
            for author in book.getElementsByTagName("author"):
                authors.append(author.childNodes[0].data)
            writer.writerow([c.next()] + [titleValue] + authors)

# Create XML objects            
doc = parse('library3.xml')
myLibrary = doc.getElementsByTagName("library")[0]

# Call function
writeToCSV(myLibrary)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - the getAttributes line was what I as after there - that has solved it!
James